# In R, use regular expression to match multiple patterns and add new column to list

Tags: regex, r, grepl

I've found numerous examples of how to match and update an entire list with one pattern and one replacement, but what I am looking for now is a way to do this for multiple patterns and multiple replacements in a single statement or loop.

Example:

```
> print(recs)
  phonenumber amount
1     5345091    200
2     5386052    200
3     5413949    600
4     7420155    700
5     7992284    600
```

I would like to insert a new column called 'service_provider' with /^5/ as Company1 and /^7/ as Company2.

I can do this with the following two lines of R:

```
recs$service_provider[grepl("^5", recs$phonenumber)]<-"Company1"
recs$service_provider[grepl("^7", recs$phonenumber)]<-"Company2"
```

Then I get:

```
  phonenumber amount service_provider
1     5345091    200          Company1
2     5386052    200          Company1
3     5413949    600          Company1
4     7420155    700          Company2
5     7992284    600          Company2
```

I'd like to provide a list, rather than discrete set of grepl's so it is easier to keep country specific information in one place, and all the programming logic in another.

```
thisPhoneCompanies<-list(c('^5','Company1'),c('^7','Company2'))
```

In other languages I would use a for loop on on the Phone Company list

```
For every row in thisPhoneCompanies
    Add service provider to matched entries in recs (such as the grepl statement)
end loop
```

But I understand that *isn't the way to do it* in R.

Comment: Package `stringi` is your friend: http://docs.rexamine.com/R-man/stringi/stringi-arguments.html

Comment: Store your data in a data.frame, like `phcomp <- data.frame(ph=c(5,7),comp=c("Comp1","Comp2"))` and then match to it based on your main data `df$new <- phcomp$comp[match(substr(df$phonenumber,1,1), phcomp$ph)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `stringi` :

```
library(stringi)
recs$service_provider <- stri_replace_all_regex(str = recs$phonenumber,
                                        pattern = c('^5.*','^7.*'), 
                                        replacement = c('Company1', 'Company2'),
                                        vectorize_all = FALSE)

recs
#   phonenumber amount service_provider
# 1     5345091    200         Company1
# 2     5386052    200         Company1
# 3     5413949    600         Company1
# 4     7420155    700         Company2
# 5     7992284    600         Company2
```

Comment: I combined the two options a little bit: thisPhoneCompanies<-data.frame(pattern=c('^5[0-9]{6}','^7[0-9]{6}'),company=c("Company1","Company2")) and then plugged these into the stri_replace_all function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @thelatemail

Looks like if I use a dataframe instead of a list for the phone companies:

```
phcomp <- data.frame(ph=c(5,7),comp=c("Company1","Company2"))
```

I can match and add a new column to my list of phone numbers in a single command (using the match function).

```
recs$service_provider <- phcomp$comp[match(substr(recs$phonenumber,1,1), phcomp$ph)]
```

Looks like I lose the ability to use regular expressions, but the matching here is very simple, just the first digit of the phone number.